# Simple SQL - count function

Tags: sql, mysql, count

My MySQL table is simple. I have 3 fields:

- an index
- a url
- a title

making up 20 records.

I'm trying to count the number of rows so that I can paginate with PHP. But count(*) is returning more than the number of rows that are there, 142 total. I get the same results counting the index.

What am I missing?

*edit*

Sorry for the previous lack of information, quite frankly I'm embarrassed by all this and feel pretty stupid.  But here goes.

```
Field: i, int(11), PRI, NOT NULL, auto_increment
Field: url, text
Field: title, mediumtext
```

The sql:

```
select count(*) from $table
```

The php:

```
require_once('highlights_db.php');

$query = "select count(*) from highlights";

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$pages = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$pages = floor($pages);

for($i = 0; $i < $pages; $i++){
    echo "<a href=\"\" class=\"page_dot\"></a><br />\n";   
}
```

Comment: can you post the actual SQL statement that you use?

Comment: Please post:

DESCRIBE <table>
SELECT * FROM <table>
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table>

Comment: no sql statement, no table description (even the relation between table is enough).How can we help you?

Comment: Don't forget that tables have names as well as columns.  This is a surprisingly common defect in SQL questions.

Comment: We're dealing with "abouts." What, exactly, does `select count(*) from tbl` and `select * from tbl` each return?

Comment: Are you comparing the right table on the same server (when comparing actual number of rows vs count)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know so sure that there are 20 rows?

This query:

```
select * from $table
```

should return the same number of rows as this number tells you:

```
select count(*) from $table`
```

If it doesn't, your table has probably been updated in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNT(i)` or something similar.

Comment: COUNT(*) counts the number of rows - period.  COUNT(Column) counts the number of rows where the named Column contains a non-NULL value.  You could be onto the right problem - but your description of it leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have **duplicate records** in your table and comparing `COUNT(*)` with the number of records returned by some sort of `SELECT DISTINCT` ?
That's about the only explanation I can see until you post the actual queries and their resultsets... (both the "count" one and the "list" one that made you see a discrepancy)

Answer (score 0):

"$pages = floor($pages);" looks odd.Shouldn't it be:`$pages = floor($pages);`?

I.e.my guess is this is a PHP problem, not SQL.